# How to access variables declared inside try-catch block in html content?

Tags: java, jsp, scope, scriptlet

I am new to jsp, java servlets etc. I am stuck upon a problem where in I have a jsp page and it contains a try-catch block in the scriptlet. I have defined a few variables inside that try-catch block which i need to access in the HTML. Since it's inside the try-catch block the html page can't access those variables and their member variables.

```
<%
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("abcd.jsp");
    try{
        UserProfile u = su.getUserProfile(session,request);
        String rec_typestr = request.getParameter("rectype");;
        int rectype = Integer.parseInt(rec_typestr);
        ....
        ....
        //some more code
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        logger.error("Error in the request: " + e.getMessage());
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "Invalid rectype passed in request");
        return;
    }
%>

<div id="testDiv1">
    <div class="testClass1">
        Private Views for <%=u.getFirstName() + " "%> <%=u.getLastName()%>
    </div>
    <div class="testClass2">
        <input type="button" value="Create" class="genericButton" onclick="displayLink('openSomePage.jsp?rectype=<%=rectype%>')" /> 
        <input type="button" value="Refresh" class="genericButton" onclick="perform1stTask()" /> 
            <input type="button" value="Print" class="genericButton" onclick="perform2ndTask()" /> 
            <input type="button" value="Export to Excel" class="genericButton" onclick="perform3rdTask(<%=u.getId()%>,'<%=someTestVariable%>', '<%=rec_typestr%>')" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Now variables *u*, *rectype_str* and *rectype* if declared outside try can be accessed by the html page but i want to access them after including them in try due to some other validations which are confidential for public forum.

**Since if the exception is caught then the error page is returned and the html content doesn't need to load, I want a solution to load this html content only when try block was successfully executed without any exceptions.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood your requirement, you can do it as follows:

```
<%
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("abcd.jsp");
    try{
        UserProfile u = su.getUserProfile(session,request);
        String rec_typestr = request.getParameter("rectype");;
        int rectype = Integer.parseInt(rec_typestr);
        ....
        ....
        //some more code
%>
        <div id="testDiv1">
            <div class="testClass1">
                Private Views for <%=u.getFirstName() + " "%> <%=u.getLastName()%>
            </div>
            <div class="testClass2">
                <input type="button" value="Create" class="genericButton" onclick="displayLink('openSomePage.jsp?rectype=<%=rectype%>')" /> 
                <input type="button" value="Refresh" class="genericButton" onclick="perform1stTask()" /> 
                    <input type="button" value="Print" class="genericButton" onclick="perform2ndTask()" /> 
                    <input type="button" value="Export to Excel" class="genericButton" onclick="perform3rdTask(<%=u.getId()%>,'<%=someTestVariable%>', '<%=rec_typestr%>')" />
            </div>
        </div>

<%        
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        logger.error("Error in the request: " + e.getMessage());
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "Invalid rectype passed in request");
        return;
    }
%>
```